# How to fetch a WebElement of a control in jsp page using selenium +C#.NET

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

[image]After login in to a website it leads to the following  https://xxx.xxx-xxxx.com/xxx/xxx/content/container.jsp. In this page, there is no option in right click to inspect element to fetch WebElements. So, by pressing F12 the WebElement  is selected. The Xpath is copied from there and wrote the  selenium script and applied assert. While executing the TestMethod, NoSuchElementException is thrown or Time out Exception is thrown.

Please give a solution for it

In this jsp page, it contains a menu items Say Item X, Item Y... so on

The Item Y is inscpected as follows:

Item Y

Could you tell me the correct format of its XPath  which will be identified while executing the testcase:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='subTabDivContainer']//a[text()='Item Y']")).Displayed)
```

Also, please let me know whether this control is disabled. If so, how to make it visible while executing?

```
    try
    {

     if((driver.FindElement(By.XPath(
           "//[@id='subTabDivContainer']//a[text()='Item Y']")).Displayed))
           {
                Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
                builder.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*@id='subTabDivContainer']//a[text()='Item Y']"))).Click().Build().Perform();
                Console.WriteLine(" Selenium mouse action has worked");

                NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsTrue(true);
            }
            else
            {
                NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsTrue(false);
            }
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
        {
            NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsTrue(false);
        }
```

Expected Result: Click operation in Item Y should be working
Actual Result: NoSuchElementException is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath to check whether it work.

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(.,'My Timesheet')]"))).Click().Build().Perform();
```

OR

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='subTabDivContainer']//a[contains(.,'My Timesheet')]"))).Click().Build().Perform();
```

Comment: thanks for responding but  that too ended up with an exception.no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='subTabDivContainer']//a[contains(.,'My Timesheet')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Comment: Did you try the first one?

Comment: Yes, first one also returns the same type of exception.no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(.,'My Timesheet')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Comment: String toEnable = "document.querySelector('#subTabDivContainer > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a').removeAttribute('disabled');";
                ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(toEnable); I have used the above code or disabling the element but that too end up with an exception An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: javascript error: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null
..Please reply if anyone knows to make it correct

Comment: Is there any plugins required for accessing the WebElements of a .jsp page in selenium

Comment: Instead of snapshot can you share html?